# Por qual meio o Android atualiza automaticamente o calendário?

Tags: android, servlet, google-calendar

Estou desenvolvendo um app que fica conectado em uma rede local, porém sem internet. Estou usando uma placa APC 8750 http://apc.io/products/8750a  sem bateria, ou seja quando desliga perde o calendário. Por qual meio o Android atualiza automaticamente o calendário? Se no caso o Android usar um servidor de data e hora ou NTP na internet, como fazer para alterar o servidor para uma servlet em um servidor nesta mesma rede local por exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Nas configurações padrões do Android, ele utiliza o horário e fuso da rede de celular e para alterar a data e hora do aparelho você precisará que ele esteja rooteado, pois não existe permissão a nível de aplicação de acessar este recurso do celular.

Comment: Na verdade esta APC 8750 usa um Android 2.3 modificado para uma versão decktop (mouse e teclado). Notei que quando há conexão com a internet, o horário atualiza corretamente. Estou em contado com apc.io mas ta muito complicado, simplesmente não respondem. Mesmo assim obrigado ACDias.

Comment: acredito que mesmo modificado, a permissão de alteração do horário mantém o mesmo padrão de somente usuário system ter permissão. Aqui parecer ter uma solução (caso esteja rooteado) para o problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android

Comment: Hj recebi uma resposta bem interessante, a APC 8750 vem sem a bateria para o seu RTC, soldei uma bateria no local indicado e pronto.